# Recursive solution to display array of linear linked list

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am working on a recursive solution to display an entire array of linear linked lists. This is not homework but in preparation for a test, I have coming.

I currently have some segmentation faults, but I'm not sure why. I have a feeling I am having issues with the pointer comparison section of this code.
What seems to be happening is I'm going out of bounds, for example,
I had 4 lists of

```
List1 - 1 2 3 4 5
List2 - 5 4 3 2 1
List3 - 1 3 2 4 5
List4 - 2 4 3 1 5
```

my function would display:

```
1 2 3 4 5
5 4 3 2 1
1 3 2 4 5
2 4 3 1 5
size is: 4
```

I would display all lists and seg fault after, however, I'm not sure what the reason is, the only reasonable suspicion I have would point to the section of code where I check for pointer comparison. I don't often post on stack overflow, so, if I have any formatting issues, please direct me accordingly.

```
//simple struct with int data
struct node
{
    int data; 
    node* next;
}

//table class has:
//array of linear linked lists
//size of array
class table
{
public:
/*

assume constructors and destructors are properly implemented

*/

    void display();
    void displayArr(node** head);
    void traverse(node* head);

    private:
    void traverseLLL(node* head);
    void displayArr(node** head);

    node** head;
    int size;
}

//wrapper
void table::display()
{
     displayArr(head);
}

//takes in array of pointer
void table::displayArr(node** head)
{

    //if no array
    if(!head) return;

    if(*head == head[size-1]) //pointer comparison, check bounds
    {
    //enter block, on last index
    cout << "size is: " << size << endl;
    traverse(*head); //do this
    return; //get out
    }
    else //not on last index
    {
    traverse(*head); //display
    ++head; //increment index
    displayArr(head); //recursive call

}

//traverse to the end of a LLL and displays it
void table::traverse(node* head) 
{
    if(!head) return;

    cout << head->data << endl;

    traverse(head->next);
}
```

Comment: Why are you making this so complicated? You can easily implement a **linear linked list** and then make an array of that.
The way you have implemented is wrong. If you wanted to make it in OOPs way. First you should have made a **linear linked list** and then you should have implemented **array of linked list** above that(__inherit linear linked list class__).

Comment: this code is pre-written by an instructor, I would totally do it a different way as well.

Comment: You should mention that in question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `head[size-1]`. You should remember the `head` pointer has been moved during the recursion.

You can use another name than `head` in `displayArr` to avoid override the class member `head` which records the real head of list.

Well, it seems easier to rename the member `head` to `_head`, and change `head[size-1]` to `_head[size-1]`

Comment: Found it, thank you! I changed the name of my variable and checked for:

if(*array == head[size-1]) 
and got no seg faults !